# can't restart apache2 segmentation fault

Tags: server, apache2, phpmyadmin

I have install apache and phpmyadmin before phpmyadmin installed my apache work fine but after install phpmyadmin my apache can't start and restart with error like this

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
Segmentation fault
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

i have try to search the same trouble in google, but i can't find the same error.

this my error log :

```
[Fri Sep 23 10:32:13.032287 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3809:tid 140371482265472] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 23 10:32:13.032398 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3809:tid 140371482265472] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Sep 23 10:40:26.860892 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3809:tid 140371482265472] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Sep 23 10:40:27.922824 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10375] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 23 10:40:27.922911 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10375] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Sep 23 10:40:29.210515 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10375] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Sep 23 10:40:30.328600 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10461] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 23 10:40:30.328663 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10461] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Sep 23 10:41:36.248034 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10461] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Sep 23 10:41:37.268526 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10523] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 23 10:41:37.268591 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10523] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Sep 23 10:56:39.090487 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10523] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Fri Sep 23 10:56:40.103084 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10523] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 23 10:56:40.103119 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10523] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Sep 23 10:56:47.198480 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10523] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

how to solve this and make apache work again?

thankyou

Comment: What's the output of `sudo systemctl status apache2`

Comment: @Zzzach...  * apache2 is not running. i can't use systemctl just use sudo service apache2 status

Comment: Okay, have you made any recent changes to your config files? The 'configtest' suggests maybe there's an error in the configuration, but it is also saying Segmetation fault, so it might be a version issue. Is everything up-to-date?